# How to define a constant in a javascript class (ECMAScript 6)?

Tags: javascript, class, constants

I'm looking for a way to declare a constant in a javascript class.
I thought it may be something like that, but no :

```
class myClass {

const MY_CONSTANT = 1;

constructor() {
    ...
    }
```

The goal is to use thoses constant from other methods in the class.

```
   myMethod (add) {
   let x = add + MY_CONSTANT;
   ...
}
```

Any idea of the correct implementation ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want a constant static value (`myClass.MY_CONSTANT`) or a constant on each instance (`var o = new myClass(); o.MY_CONSTANT`)?

Comment: constant static value. But i need to access it from other methods inside the class itself

Comment: "access it from inside the class itself" What do you mean? By doing `this.MY_CONSTANT` or `myClass.MY_CONSTANT`?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited my previous comment. I mean from other methods of the class. I also edited my question for better understanding.